# Webpack-dev-server ignore node_modules

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

When run webpack-dev-server like this:

```
webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.dev.js
```

The terminal will console like these, lot's of console.
How ignore the node_modules?

```
bundle.js  4.11 MB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 1.43 MB [rendered]
    [0] multi main 64 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] ./~/babel-polyfill/lib/index.js 907 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] ./~/core-js/shim.js 7.38 kB {0} [built]
    [3] ./~/core-js/modules/es6.symbol.js 8.93 kB {0} [built]
    ...
   [18] ./~/core-js/modules/_redefine.js 1.05 kB {0} [built]
   [19] ./~/core-js/modules/_uid.js 158 bytes {0} [built]
   [20] ./~/core-js/modules/_ctx.js 505 bytes {0} [built]
   [21] ./~/core-js/modules/_a-function.js 120 bytes {0} [built]
   ...
  [648] ./~/ansi-regex/index.js 135 bytes {0} [built]
  [649] (webpack)/hot/only-dev-server.js 2.25 kB {0} [built]
  [650] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 813 bytes {0} [built]
```

Comment: Nobody can help me about this...Please Who can teach me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. In my webpack.config.dev.js add config like this:

```
devServer: {
  stats: {
    chunks: false
  },
},
```

Comment: That will only stop the stats from being shown. If you don't want `node_modules` to be processed, look at [`module.loaders.exclude`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders).

Comment: Actually I do it like you say:
```
{
  test: /\.js?$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules)/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
}
```
But It looks like unuseful on webpack-dev-server

Comment: This answer explains *what* you did, but in no way answers *how* you fixed the problem, or *why* this fixes the problem.